# how to get "URL" "Service" "available Service" in jhipster project and Gateway Architecture

Tags: jhipster, netflix-eureka

I created an application jhipster: architecture gateway and Jhipster Registry
Normally it should show, in my gateway Page ,the current Routes 
[Gateway Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/scVsH.png)

But nothing appears !!!!
In addition in my console I have the following errors :
[console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aj3ZS.png)

Comment: Well the error just means that gateway is unable to connect to registry, is it started ? If yes, then check url in bootstrap file, check also active profile.

Comment: yes the project is started ! but no gateway link

Comment: Anyway, the error is clear, you just have to find why. Are you able to connect from a browser  to registry using same url as the one defined in your gateway bootstrap?

Comment: what is the Gateway bootstrap ?

Comment: All spring cloud applications (for Jhipster, it means gatewasy and microservices apps) use bootstrap*.yml files to load their application contexts. See http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud.html#_the_bootstrap_application_context